# Delete all row from all table from MYSQL DB with some ID clause

Tags: mysql, delete

Is it possible to delete all rows from all tables in **MYSQL** DB with `some id = '123'`.

Actually i needed this because there is lots of **junk data** in others table but in main table rows are **deleted**, i have the IDs.

Now the new logic is implemented in the right way but i have to delete previous rows. Is it possible in a single `MYSQL` query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to do it one table at a time

Answer (score 1):

Quick Solution is to populate the ids to temp table and use Delete records from the table with Join to temp table.